# Force NSSearchField to Begin Editing When It Becomes First Responder

Tags: swift, macos, nstextfield, first-responder, nspopover

I have an NSSearchField in an NSPopover. This popover is opened when an NSStatusBar item is clicked.

In my NSPopover's view controller's `viewWillAppear()`, I call         `self.view.window?.makeFirstResponder(searchField)` on my NSSearchField. I want this search field to be ready to edit when the popover is presented. By ready to edit, I mean the user will not have to click inside the NSSearchField to begin typing.

At this point, my implementation doesn't always work. Sometimes, it functions, and the popover opens with the search field ready, cursor blinking. Most of the time, however, especially if I'm editing text in a different application when I open the popover, the NSSearchField has to be clicked on to be edited.

I've subclassed the search field and overridden its `becomeFirstResponder()` method, and I can confirm it gets called every time.

How come I can't "steal" the right to edit my search field from other applications when the field becomes the first responder? Is this even possible?

Comment: It might be possible, but not recommended; stealing focus away from another application would essentially be like malware.

Comment: I see your point. That being said, some apps do it: if you're typing into a text field and open the Messages application, the NSTextField where you type your messages is automatically editable. Maybe this behavior is only available to Apple?

Comment: Usually it's helper tool for an app that would be installed then granted permission for that type of behavior; not exclusive to Apple apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the key was bringing my application to the forefront.

I was able to give my application the system's focus by calling       `NSApplication.sharedApplication().activateIgnoringOtherApps(true)`.  My NSSearchField, which was already becoming the first responder, can now directly be edited.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `viewDidAppear:` to make the search field first responder.

Usually the view is not yet in the view hierarchy, when `viewWillAppear:` is called, so the `window` property is `nil` (and your optional chaining will just not call `makeFirstResponder`).

Comment: That makes sense, but unfortunately it doesn't solve it for some reason. In both cases, whether I call this from viewWillAppear: or viewDidAppear:, the NSSearchField definitely receives the call. Additionally, if I check the window's first responder after the call, it's the NSSearchField.